# How do I get to know if my question has been commented or answered?

Tags: support, comment, answers, notifications, questions

I'm new here and I don't know how things work here and don't have any knowledge about commenting or answering questions. How do I get to know if my question has been commented or answered?

Comment: You get a notification for comments on your posts and answers to your question. In the top bar, somewhat left, a the inbox symbol gets a red badge with a number (the number of notifications since you last checked).

Comment: <i>Thanks a lot</i>

Comment: For more info, visit http://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: First step, use *real* and *actual* words. Not internet abbreviation like "cuz".

Answer (score 7):

Check your *inbox*:

[image]

Like this:

[image]

The number of unread messages will show up in red:

[image]

(thanks to Daniel Fischer for providing the last image!)

Comment: Now you have ;)

Comment: Thanks! :D ${}{}{}$

Comment: Apart from inbox, there also is [responses tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses) on the profile page. Inbox can be also accessed on the network profile, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183963/does-global-inbox-have-a-separate-url-and-page/183970#183970). The difference between inbox and responses tab is that inbox shows notifications from the whole network (all sites you're using), responses tab only shows responses from one particular site.

Answer (score 1):

Another way for this problem is to install the software of stackexchange for your device (phone or tablet with android operating system or IOS) and active notifications for this software to send you push notifications.